# Get rid of empty space above plotly chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Im trying to get rid of the empty space, especially over my plotly chart using margin but I cant. Ideally I would like no empty space all around my chart but especially the top one is very annoying.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
Value<-c(21.1, 20.9, 8.2, 14.7, 18.7, 15.8, 18.9, 24.1, 25.8, 20.5, 
         19.1, 16.2, 35.9, 21.6, 20.4, 18.1, 7.8, 14, 20.6, 19.7, 34.4, 
         21.6, 19.9, 19, 18.5, 14.6, 19.6, 19.3, 21.7, 18.3)
Country<-c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
           "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
           "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", 
           "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Norway", 
           "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
           "Sweden")
d1<-data.frame(Value,Country)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
     column(4,
            div(
              id = "frame5",
              h3("Cumulative Uptake (%) of the first vaccine dose among adults (18+) in EU/EEA countries as of 2021-04-16", style = 'font-size:15px;color:#a2a2a2;'),
              
              plotlyOutput("plot",height = 600)),
            )
      ), 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  m <- list(
    l = 0,
    r = 0,
    b = 0,
    t = 0,
    pad = 0
  )

  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
   
    fig1 <- plot_ly(d1, x = ~Value, y = ~Country,
                    type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') 
    fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(
      margin=m,
      font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
      yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",
                   showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85)),
      xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE))%>% 
      
      config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
      config(displaylogo = FALSE)
    fig1
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to avoid using the `title` argument in `layout()`?

Comment: I cant make it fit exactly inside the column.Can u do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting yaxis fixedrange to FALSE and removing domain(0, 85) made the empty space at the top go away.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
Value<-c(21.1, 20.9, 8.2, 14.7, 18.7, 15.8, 18.9, 24.1, 25.8, 20.5, 
         19.1, 16.2, 35.9, 21.6, 20.4, 18.1, 7.8, 14, 20.6, 19.7, 34.4, 
         21.6, 19.9, 19, 18.5, 14.6, 19.6, 19.3, 21.7, 18.3)
Country<-c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
           "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
           "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", 
           "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Norway", 
           "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
           "Sweden")
d1<-data.frame(Value,Country)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            column(4,
                   div(
                       id = "frame5",
                       h3("Cumulative Uptake (%) of the first vaccine dose among adults (18+) in EU/EEA countries as of 2021-04-16", style = 'font-size:15px;color:#a2a2a2;'),
                       
                       plotlyOutput("plot",height = 600)),
            )
        ), 
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
    
    m <- list(
        l = 0,
        r = 0,
        b = 0,
        t = 0,
        pad = 0
    )
    
    output$plot<-renderPlotly({
        
        fig1 <- plot_ly(d1, x = ~Value, y = ~Country,
                        type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') 
        fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(
            margin=m,
            font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
            yaxis = list(fixedrange = FALSE,title="",
                         showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE),
            xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE))%>% 
            
            config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
            config(displaylogo = FALSE)
        fig1
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```